# Automatic updating of an ORC table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to do the following thing in Hive: I create an external table stored as a Textfile and I convert this table in an ORC table (with the usual way: first create an empty ORC table, and second load the data from the original one).

For my TextFile table, my data is located in HDFS in a directory, say `/user/MY_DATA/`.

So when I add/drop files from `MY_DATA`, my TextFile table is automatically updated. Now I would like the ORC table to be automatically updated too. Do you know if this is possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no straight forward way for this, u need to add the new data in the ORC table as u did for the first load, or u can create a new orc

```
CREATE TABLE orc_emp STORED AS ORC AS SELECT * FROM employees.emp;
```

table and drop the old orc table.